# Jupyter Notebook issue - NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:snowflake`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error in Jupyter notebook running on docker.

```
NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:snowflake`
```

I'm running the following

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
    f'snowflake://asd:asd@bla/analytics/public?warehouse=general&role=analyst'
)
```

From within the Notebook I can execute the following and get the code to work, with results below:

```
!python3 --version
!echo '---'
!cat test.py
!echo '---'
!python3 test.py
```

```
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.
---
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
    f'snowflake://asd:asd@bla/analytics/public?warehouse=general&role=analyst'
)

print(engine)
---
Engine(snowflake://asd:***@bla/analytics/public?role=analyst&warehouse=general)
```

However running the same create_engine() from within the Jupyter notebook returns your error: `NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:snowflake`.

I'm really confused as to why this happens.

I even added the `pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlaclchemy` to my Dockerfile:

```
# Start from a core stack version https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html
FROM jupyter/tensorflow-notebook
# Install in the default python3 environment
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy && \
    fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR && \
    fix-permissions /home/$NB_USER
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to my notebook got it working

Hack Solution:

```
!python3 -m pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy
exit()
#once complete, go to Kernel>Restart&Clear Output
```

Better Solution:
I was not running `docker build --rm -t jupyter/sme-datascience-notebook .` after modifying my Dockerfile, this fixed it

Comment: thanks for this it has helped my engine work. However how are you importing it into a pandas dataframe? my current method takes far too long